# Asking future employer about things to brush up on

Tags: new-job, skills

I will be joining a new employer in a month. I know the specific team that I will be joining and my position will be that of a database architect. Is it good optics-wise to ask, the recruiting manager with my future employer, about specific technologies that I should brush up on before I join so that I can shorten the lead time to become productive?

Comment: Do you expect us to read your mind? 1. We don't even know what position you will be filling - I started to assume that you're going to be a software engineer but you could be the guy who takes out the trash; 2. "I can be productive right away" is a pipe dream - you don't know anything about the procedures in place at your employer's let alone where the resources you need are nor do you know who you are reporting to. The good news about taking out the trash is that you can begin to be productive right away.In general, the more skilled your work, the more time it will take you to get up to speed

Comment: Anyone who wants to be productive right away and doesn't know the setup - that person is a menace.

Comment: I see your point. I do know the specific team I will be joining and I will be joining as a database architect. May be I should have said "shorten my lead time to become productive" but that looked really wordy. Appreciate your input though.

Comment: Yes, shortening the lead time to become productive is a very good goal and you should edit your post accordingly. Your goal the first few weeks, as you become familiar with people, procedures and resources, is not to do anything stupid - that's your biggest hazard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it good optics-wise to ask, the recruiting manager with my future
>   employer, about specific technologies that I should brush up on before
>   I join so that I can begin to be productive right away?

It would be terrific to ask your future manager (not the recruiter) about what you can do to "hit the ground running".

This is something I always do. Most employers wont really give you anything, but it looks good anyway. (Great optics). Some will have you read some documentation - seldom any heavy lifting.

I once accepted a job running an IT department and asked if there was something I could do as I worked out my notice period. I was asked to come in after work one day and was given a blueprint and asked to design the layout of the new computer room. I enjoyed it, and they were very appreciative when I had it ready to go my first day.

Comment: Totally agreed. For my current job, they actually recommended a few books to look into, offering to expense them once I officially started. Was super helpful, and I definitely felt a bit ahead of the curve during the first week.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your future employer what RDBMS they are using and whether they are using the RDBMS services available from the various cloud providers.

Then have a good time gorging yourself on youtube videos until your first day of employment rolls around :)

Don't be overly ambitious - you don't have enough time to learn everything. As long as you have a grasp of the technology fundamentals, you are in good shape.